# how to get column or row number by cell value in python

Tags: python, excel

[image]

if my Excel sheet is like above picture

then how can I get the column number for MT column?

```
for mt in sheet.row_values(0):
    print mt
    if mt=='MT':
        break
```

is there any function like sheet.row_values(0).colnumber?

Comment: Should we guess the module you are using for parsing the file?

Comment: No, I just want to know if there's any ways which can help me to get colmun index by the row index and cell value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col_idx = -1
for idx, mt in enumerate(sheet.row_values(0)):
    print mt
    if mt=='MT':
        col_idx = idx
        break
```

Comment: Since you're looking for the first one, isn't this simply `sheet.row_values(0).index("MT")`?

Answer (score 0):

RickyA's can also be spelt

```
next(i for i, mt in enumerate(sheet.row_values(0)) if mt=='MT')
```

`next` can be given a default if needed.